# "sed" command in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, sed

Could someone explain this command for me:

```
cat | sed -e 's,%,$,g' | sudo tee /etc/init.d/dropbox << EOF
   echo "Hello World"
EOF
```

What does the "sed" command do?

Comment: sed is short for "stream editor" -- it edits streams of bytes/characters.

Comment: You could have asked that as a comment to my answer, I would have been glad to expand it.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sed-command-in-linux-unix-with-examples/

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`sed` is the [Stream EDitor](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed). It can do a whole pile of [really cool things](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt), but the most common is text replacement.

The `s,%,$,g` part of the command line is the `sed` command to execute. The `s` stands for substitute, the `,` characters are delimiters (other characters can be used; `/`, `:` and `@` are popular). The `%` is the pattern to match (here a literal percent sign) and the `$` is the second pattern to match (here a literal dollar sign). The `g` at the end means to `g`lobally replace on each line (otherwise it would only update the first match).

Comment: For some reason sed is replacing all lines for me, not just the first when I leave out the `g` at the end. e.g. `sudo sed -i 's,enabled=0,enabled=1,' /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` in an amazon AWS image with sed version 4.2.1

Comment: sed will always run on each line. The `g` option makes it replace every match on that line instead of the first match on that line.

Answer (score 29):

Here `sed` is replacing all occurrences of `%` with `$` in its standard input.

As an example

```
$ echo 'foo%bar%' | sed -e 's,%,$,g'
```

will produce "foo$bar$".

Answer (score 8):

It reads `Hello World` (`cat`), replaces all (`g`) occurrences of `%` by `$` and (over)writes it to `/etc/init.d/dropbox` as root.

Answer (score 1):

sed is a stream editor. I would say try man sed.If you didn't find this man page in your system refer this URL:

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed